# How to display JSON data from an API into a tableview after parsing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, swift5

I am getting JSON data from an api and I am not able to populate it to the tableview.

API Response

```
{
"inspection_data": [{
        "inspection_dt_card": "February 02, 12:17AM",
        "part_type_card": "XXYYZZ1",
        "inspection_status_card": "Bad",
        "defect_type_card": "EXTR",
        "badge_color": "danger",
        "line_id": "line-86"
    },
    {
        "inspection_dt_card": "February 02, 12:17AM",
        "part_type_card": "XXYYZZ2",
        "inspection_status_card": "Excelllent",
        "defect_type_card": "EXTR",
        "badge_color": "danger",
        "line_id": "line-99"
    }
]
```

}

The model class is as follows

```
struct InspectionDataModel: Codable {
    let inspectionData: [InspectionData]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case inspectionData = "inspection_data"
    }
}

struct InspectionData: Codable {
    let inspectionDtCard: String
    let partTypeCard: String
    let inspectionStatusCard: String
    let defectTypeCard: String
    let badgeColor: String
    let lineID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case inspectionDtCard = "inspection_dt_card"
        case partTypeCard = "part_type_card"
        case inspectionStatusCard = "inspection_status_card"
        case defectTypeCard = "defect_type_card"
        case badgeColor = "badge_color"
        case lineID = "line_id"
    }
}
```

My api call is as follows

```
AF.request(webURL,
               method: .get,
               parameters: params,
               encoding: URLEncoding.default,
               headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: InspectionDataModel.self) { response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(_):
            debugPrint(response.result)
            do {
                let decoderResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(InspectionDataModel.self, from: response.data!)
                print(decoderResponse)
            } catch { print(error) }
            break
        case .failure(_):
            debugPrint(response.data as Any)
            debugPrint(response.debugDescription)
            print("Failed")
        }
    }
```

Debug Print Output

```
InspectionDataModel(inspectionData: [Worker_App.InspectionData(inspectionDtCard: "February 07, 01:48PM", partTypeCard: "XXYYZZ1", inspectionStatusCard: "Bad", defectTypeCard: "EXTR", badgeColor: "danger", lineID: "line-86"), Worker_App.InspectionData(inspectionDtCard: "February 07, 01:48PM", partTypeCard: "XXYYZZ1", inspectionStatusCard: "Excelllent", defectTypeCard: "EXTR", badgeColor: "danger", lineID: "line-99")])
```

I am not able to parse the response and populate it on the table.

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you see any of the debugPrint outputs? And can you also add the code related to your table?

Comment: @koen Added debugPrint output. Once I get the parsed data into a variable, I can reload the table and populate the table with data. But i am stuck at parsing and storing the data from api part.

Answer (score 0):

You ignore the actual – already decoded – result, the associated value in the `success` case. And also the real error in the `failure` case.

It's much simpler

```
AF.request(webURL,
           method: .get,
           parameters: params,
           encoding: URLEncoding.default,
           headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: InspectionDataModel.self) { response in
    switch response.result {
        case .success(let decoderResponse):
            debugPrint(decoderResponse)

        case .failure(let error):
            debugPrint("Failed", error)
    }
}
```

`decoderResponse` contains the decoded `InspectionDataModel` struct

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you please tell me how to store the data in the decoderResponse into a variable and then populate it into a tableview?

I tried creating a variable like this (private var inspectionDataObj = [InspectionDataModel]()) in the VC, but I am not able to successfully store it. Seems like I am missing something out.

Comment: If you want the array of `InspectionData` declare `var inspections = [InspectionData]()` and assign `inspections = decoderResponse.inspectionData`. To populate the table view there are countless examples and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks @vadian. Really appreciate your efforts in helping me out.

Answer (score -1):

Try this Model with an array

Array.append(your model(keys and values))

And call array in table view cell like
array[indexPath.row]. inspection_dt_card

```
struct InspectionDataModel {

    var inspection_dt_card = String()
    var partTypeCard = String()
    var inspection_status_card = String()
    var defect_type_card = String()
    var badge_color = String()
    var line_id = String()
    
    init() {
        inspection_dt_card = ""
        partTypeCard = ""
        inspection_status_card = ""
        defect_type_card = ""
        badge_color = ""
        line_id = ""
    }
    
    init(data: AnyObject) {
        
        if let value = data["inspection_dt_card"] as? String {
            inspection_dt_card = value
        } else {
            inspection_dt_card = ""
        }
        
        if let value = data["partTypeCard"] as? String {
            partTypeCard = value
        } else {
            partTypeCard = ""
        }
        
        if let value = data["inspection_status_card"] as? String {
            inspection_status_card = value
        } else {
            inspection_status_card = ""
        }

        if let value = data["defect_type_card"] as? String {
            defect_type_card = value
        } else {
            defect_type_card = ""
        }

        if let value = data["badge_color"] as? String {
            badge_color = value
        } else {
            badge_color = ""
        }

        if let value = data["line_id"] as? String {
            line_id = value
        } else {
            line_id = ""
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).